# In GitLab CI, is there a way to define pipeline variables in a Merge Request?

Tags: gitlab-ci

In a Merge Request I want to specify a variable which can be used inside the pipeline.

I was thinking about giving the Merge Request labels but can I read them inside the pipeline job?

Answer (score 2):

As you can read here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html, you can simply just use the variable
`CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS` in your pipeline.

To check if a specific label is set, add this to your `- only` section of a step like so:

```
testing:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test-ci
  only:
    - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS=="mylabel"
```

The documentation says, that the variable contains all labels separated by comma. I do not know how to check if the string mylabel is included. But the above should work if mylabel is the only label for the merge request.

Comment: oh looks exactly like what I was looking for!
I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I could also disable the automatically pipeline trigger of the Merge Request and trigger one manually. There I can define variables, which of course can be used inside the pipeline.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/